# How to prove $C^1$ class is a proper subset of Lipschitz class?

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $Lip(A)$ be the set of vector-valued functions $f$ on the closed set $A\in\mathbb R^n$ such that 
$$f(0)=0,$$
$$||f|| \text{ is finite, where by definition: } ||f||=\sup \{\frac{||f(x)-f(y)||}{||x-y||}:x\neq y\}.$$

Show that $C^1(A)$ (Continuously differentiable function on A) is a proper subset of $Lip(A)$.

My concern: $f(x)=|x|$ is $Lip(A)$ but not $C^1(A)$, this proves the proper part. For the subset part, it seems that I need $A$ to be bounded (otherwise the derivative can go to infinity).

Any thoughts how to prove the subset part?

Comment: What does $C^1$ mean on an arbitrary closed set?

Comment: @GCD Continuously differentiable function on that closed set.

Comment: Yes, but usually we define differentiability on open sets. Do you mean functions which extend to be $C^1$ on the whole Euclidean space?

Comment: Your concern is spot on, the counterexample is $A = \mathbb{R}$, $f(x) = e^x$.

Comment: @GCD I think so. Hence the derivative need not to be bounded. Isn't it?

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko Well, that is not a counter example in this case, $ f(0) = 1 $, but $ e^x -1 $ should work.